# Clear only selected notification in flutter firebase messaging

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13, I will receive more number of notifications in the app,

**Issue:**
when I tap a notification, the app will opened and the remaining notifications will be cleared in the phone.

**Expected behavior:**
When I tap a notification, only that particular notification should be cleared, the remaining should stay in the notification tray.

Issue exists in iOS only

Any Solution please guide.